# VueJS : binded methods modify model but do not update the view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to VueJS and I created a MVC application which has a Clock. This clock updates other instanciated models of the application. But the problem is that the views of the instances are not updated...

I found the problem, it comes from binding methods. When bound methods are called, Vue doesn't know that the data changed.

Here is a simple example of the problem:
This is a simple class which possesses a year, which can be increased with three methods:

- `increaseYear1()` directly increases the attribute.
- `increaseYear2()` calls `increaseYear1()` but bound in the constructor to an attribute of the object.
- `increaseYear3()` calls `increaseYear1()` but the bind is done in the method itself.

```
export default class MyModel {
    constructor(year) {
        this.year = year
        this.function = this.increaseYear1.bind(this)
    }

    increaseYear1() {
        this.year++
    }

    increaseYear2() {
        this.function()
    }

    increaseYear3() {
        const test = this.increaseYear1.bind(this)
        test()
    }
}
```

Here is the view :

```
<template>
    {{ model.year }}<br />
    <button @click="model.increaseYear1()">Increase Year 1</button><br />
    <button @click="model.increaseYear2()">Increase Year 2</button><br />
    <button @click="model.increaseYear3()">Increase Year 3</button><br />
</template>

<script>
import MyModel from './model'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            model: new MyModel(2021),
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

All methods update the value. But the second does not update the view. Why ? Is there a solution to counter that ? My entire application is based on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that you're using VUE 3 and the states that you want to change are in their own class instance.
The solution could be warp them inside `reactive` function.

```
import { reactive } from vue

export default class MyModel {
    constructor(year) {
        this.year = reactive({value: year})
        this.function = this.increaseYear1.bind(this)
    }
    ...
}
```

read more about reactive here https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#how-rendering-reacts-to-changes

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tested on the example : "value cannot be made reactive: 2021". And it's not working :(

Comment: I cloned your code and it's working just fine for me even without reactive function

Comment: Mmmh strange, we are 2 and it's not working for my collegue neither. Did you try to use the second button ? This is the one which do not update the view

Comment: I added screenshots to my answer, I have tried all the functions and seems to work just fine

Comment: Ok I don't know why it works for you, maybe you have a greater vue version? But it seems like reactive is working for my project! Instead of giving a method, I give the object and a method to the Clock. The Clock will then call the "update" method. I bind the object and use reactive like this :  `this.function = obj[method].bind(reactive(obj))` works like a charm